# How is compound finance Index calculated?

Tags: solidity, defi

in the compound whitepaper there is a section on how to calculate accured interest rate. It is calculated with historical index of the borrowing interest rate.

This is the how they calculate it:

[image: compoundWhitePaper]

How can I "translate" this into solidity?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can see the code that they write.the url si https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-money-market/blob/master/contracts/MoneyMarket.sol.
the fuction name is 'calculateInterestIndex'.

hope this helps.

Comment: i am wrong.you show whitepaper is new compound code's. we need  to see the new code.